# Understanding Syntax issues about Parse latest SDK / Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode-6.2

Why does the 2nd snippet work and the first not work?

This code **does not work**:

```
func logIn() {
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(tv_username.text, password:tv_password.text) {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            // Yes, User Exists
            //self.loginInitialLabel.text = "User Exists"
        } else {
            // No, User Doesn't Exist
        }
    }
}
```

This code **works**:

```
func logIn() {
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(tv_username.text, password:tv_password.text) {
        (user, error) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            // Yes, User Exists
            //self.loginInitialLabel.text = "User Exists"
        } else {
            // No, User Doesn't Exist
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error message. I am looking for a clear explanation of why some online docs have hte first example but only the 2nd one works. Did Parse change their SDK without changing documentation or is this some artifact of  Swift 1.2 change? I am using XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2.

[image]

Zoom of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full error message please? It's cut off in your image

Comment: This looks like an SDK change. I think what you're seeing is the difference between named return variables and anonymous return variables.

Comment: @TommyBs Updated question with the complete error message

Answer (score 1):

- In the first example, you specify the types of `user` and `error` explicitly (`PFUser!` and `NSError!`) respectively.
- In the second example, you permit the type of `user` and `error` to be supplied implicitly.

Thus, the fact that the first example gives a compile error must mean that your explicit types are no longer correct. It could be the exclamation marks; try removing them.

The real way to figure out what types they are, though, is to use the second example, compile it, and then to put the cursor inside `user` and then inside `error` and read off the types from Quick Help on the right side of the Xcode window, as I do here:

[image]

That little trick has solved many Swift type mysteries for me!